# Using UNION select inside a view

Tags: sql-server, union, distinct, sql-view

I have a requirement to check if a specific user is already being referenced to one of our transaction tables (we have around 10 transaction tables). I suggested using a VIEW that will contain all the users that are already referenced, then the DEV team could just SELECT through that table to find out if the data they're looking for is there or not,

so here's my query for the view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_ID
FROM transaction_table_1

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT user_ID
FROM transaction_table_2

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT user_ID
FROM transaction_table_3

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT user_ID
FROM transaction_table_4

[...]
```

Right now it works, but my question is, is this a good idea? The requirement asks that I only provide a script (or a view) and not a stored procedure, I think this would  be better with an SP since I could just do a quick IF EXIST() statement for each of the table and just check if the parameter user exists in any of the table, but they really wanted it to be only a script they could check (and no using of variables).

Can you guys give me advice on a better way of doing this requirement, that would have less impact on performance since this may not be the optimized solution for this requirement.

TIA,
Rommel

Comment: IF EXISTS() is the fastest solution. What do you mean by not using variables? How would it work w/o variables and this view that you have now?

Comment: They're using hibernate to get data from the DB and when I suggested a script that uses variables "Declare @status INT", they said it won't work and it would be better if I can provide with just a query, so I suggested using a view. The original plan I think was to use IF EXISTS() but they didn't want to dip into the DB more than once just to check if the user they're looking for has already made a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can remove the `DISTINCT` because `UNION` already makes it :)

```
SELECT user_ID
FROM transaction_table_1

UNION

SELECT user_ID
FROM transaction_table_2

UNION

SELECT user_ID
FROM transaction_table_3

UNION

SELECT user_ID
FROM transaction_table_4
```

But since you have to use a view, I don't see how to make it differently.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But would the union still be a good idea? I think they would be okay if this was a SELECT script, but with the number of tables required to look at, I am not sure a SELECT statement would be good. What I am afraid of, is that as more transactions are placed on the transaction tables that the performance will take a hit.

Comment: you can't run away from a union, now you can make UNION like I state or UNION ALL and distinct like @Paddy stated.

Answer (score 1):

From a performance point of view I would structure the query slightly differently:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_ID
FROM (

    SELECT user_ID
    FROM transaction_table_1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT user_ID
    FROM transaction_table_2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT user_ID
    FROM transaction_table_3

    ...
) x
```

This will reduce the number of unique index scans that need to be done to 1 - rather than having one each time a `UNION` is performed

Comment: Yeah people tend to not know/forget that UNION discards dupes - UNION ALL includes all rows whereas UNION does extra work to exclude duplicates

Comment: Thanks Paddy, I will be looking into this.